# React Hook useState show errors

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hi I am trying the write a react component, but it shows the error as following, I am sure renderContent is a react function component but this error keep showing up. [image]

below is my renderContent component

```
export const renderContent = () => { 
  const [input, setInput] = useState(''); 
  return ( 
    <form>
     <input
      type="text"
      onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}
      value={input}
      onBlur={() =>delay(() =>setInput(''),150}
      placeholder='placeholder here...'
     />
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: yes I did imported react

Comment: React components have to start with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 3):

React components should follow PascalCase naming convention.
In other words change **renderContent** to **RenderContent** and everything should work fine.